# Kafka 1.0.x Delete consumer group

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to delete an unused consumer group. Since I'm using version 1.0.x, based on the official docs

```
When using the new consumer API (where the broker handles coordination of partition handling and rebalance), the group is deleted when the last committed offset for that group expires.
```

the configuration properties prescribing this behavior in my case are

```
#set offset retention to 2 weeks
offsets.retention.minutes=20160
```

I could only find these in the `server.properties`. There's no mention of them in the Consumer Config logged upon the startup of the application

Trying to re-configure the group so that `offsets.retention.minutes=0`, I could not find a definitive answer. I'm quite surprised that one cannot change this using `kafka-consumer-groups` on a group level... Can this be so involved?

I know that there is a [deleteConsumerGroups](https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/Admin.html#deleteConsumerGroups-java.util.Collection-) API but this as introduced in version 1.1.x. Is the only way to delete this group to just wait for the offsets to expire?

Comment: In end I just let the retention policy take its toll on the topic. After two weeks the consumer group got deleted automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to cleanup groups is changing the retention time for the `__consumer_offsets` topic. You cannot target individual groups (or records in that topic)

I believe the `deleteConsumerGroups` call pushes a null value for the the group name into that topic, and you still need to wait for the topic to be compacted for a group to actually be removed